# Only show redo search button when user has completely moved to a new area

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

How can i only show the redo button only when the user has changed region?In my code right now it keeps flickering on and off as the region changes, not sure what is missing.

**Code:**

app.js

```
onregionchange() {
    this.setState({redosearch: !this.state.redosearch })
}

render() {
    const Showredo = ({redosearch }) => redosearch ? <View><Text> redo now <Text></View> : null
    return(
    <View>
    {this.state.redosearch  ? <ShowRedo  redosearch={this.state.redosearch }/> : null}
    <View>
        <MapView
            ref={(map) => (this.map = map)}
            style={styles.map}
            onRegionChange={this.onregionchange}
        >
        </MapView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I notice may be causing an issue here. First, it looks like you may be double checking the state value; inside the Showredo element property and again inside the return value. second, The code has two open View tags and two Text tags with no close. Third, I can't see if the function onregionchange is bound or not. And finally, you're returning two elements in the render function (or actually missing two view closing tags at the end)

try to change your code to this which should correct all of those:

```
onregionchange = () => {
    this.setState({redosearch: !this.state.redosearch })
}

render() {
    const { redosearch } = this.state;
    return([
    <View key="a_key_for_element_1">
        {redosearch ? <View><Text> redo now </Text></View> : null}
    </View>,
    <MapView 
        key="a_key_for_element_2"
        ref={(map) => (this.map = map)}
        style={styles.map}
        onRegionChange={this.onregionchange}
    >
    </MapView>]
    );
}
```

Comment: its still flickering, as it was before. any idea?